# How to overcome an issue once test failed due to network issue but on retry test has been succeeded thus Newman will return Success

Tags: postman, newman

I’m searching for a solution for a following issue:

There is a user-flow (folder with a list of requests with a relevant tests).
User-flow running under Newman + htmlextra ci/cd pipeline
User-flow running on test environments which is has 3 party dependencies (services, networking etc)
The issue is the network timeouts, socket hang up.
Which is why i added a kind of retry mechanism in postman
that allows me to repeat the requests once test got status code 5xx

[Print screen: User-Flow report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhf9e.png)

So eventually the user-flow itself pass as you see at the print screen
(the second retry succeeded) but Newman return fail on such user-flow
once we got at least one timeout.

The question is: How i can overcome such issue
Once the retry succeeded i would like Newman will return Success (exit code 0)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the image : [image]

Just imagine : You are getting 5xx series code on "Code Generation" request and you want to retry until you get 2xx series. use the following code for that.

```
if(responseCode.code!=200){
    postman.setNextRequest("Code Generation");
}
```

> pass the request name in setNextRequest